# Convert DOCX table with cells that span multiple columns or rows to Markdown

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

Pandoc supports convert [table with cells that span multiple columns or rows](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables) from Markdown to DOCX, for example

```
---
title: MWE
---

Lorem ipsum

+---------------------+-----------------------+
| Location            | Temperature 1961-1990 |
|                     | in degree Celsius     |
|                     +-------+-------+-------+
|                     | min   | mean  | max   |
+=====================+=======+=======+=======+
| Antarctica          | -89.2 | N/A   | 19.8  |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
| Earth               | -89.2 | 14    | 56.7  |
+---------------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

will be convert into

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Word showing table with cells that span multiple columns or rows]

Is the reverse operation possible? Convert the table from DOCX to Markdown?

I tried `pandoc --from docx --to markdown+grid_tables` but it produces

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Location                          Temperature                
                                    1961-1990 in               
                                    degree                     
                                    Celsius                    
  --------------------------------- ------------- ------------ ------------
                                    min           mean         max

  Antarctica                        -89.2         N/A          19.8

  Earth                             -89.2         14           56.7
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did you try the newest pandoc version? this should have been implemented in https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/56b211120c62a01f8aba1c4512acfe4677d8c7d0

Comment: I tested with pandoc 3.1.11.1 that is the newest version.

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of the Markdown writer.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc's Markdown writter (version 3.1.11.1) does not support rowspan and colspan. There is a open feature request for it at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8990.